# Can't succesffully install RVM in Ubuntu 11

Tags: ubuntu, bash, bashrc, rvm

I've installed RVM before in Debian and OSX without any problems, but doing it in Ubuntu is driving me crazy.

I´ve tried different tutorials, [this](http://www.giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=1792) is the last of them. I think everything goes smoothly until I have to update .bashrc, which doesnt seem to do anything. When I check if RVM is recognized as a function with `$ type rvm | head -n1` I only get "not found". And if I try to execute RVM I get a "rvm is not installed" message.

Maybe this tutorials are outdated? Can anyone help? This is a fresh install of Ubuntu 11 running on Virtualbox, if that's useful.

This is how my .bashrc looks now, after trying another method suggested [in the comments here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367423/issue-installing-rvm-for-ror-in-ubuntu)

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return

# don't put duplicate lines in the history. See bash(1) for more options
# ... or force ignoredups and ignorespace
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:ignorespace

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "$debian_chroot" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ] && ! shopt -oq posix; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
fi



export PATH=~/.rvm/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: You've made sure to log on again, or open a new terminal after updating `.bashrc` ?

Comment: Yes I did Kvisle. By the way, I found a question for the same problem but it wasnt of any help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, problem solved. For some reason RVM was being installed in a slightly different path, so the line that every tutorial told me to add to -bashrc was not working.
If anyone encounters this same problem, check that the path in that line really exists. If it doesnt, remove .rvm and reinstall it.

Answer (score 1):

I have have installed RVM a few months back and I used most of this tutorial. (skipped the Capistrano bit)

Try this website [Installing Ruby on Rails Ubuntu](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/06/21/set-up-an-ubuntu-local-development-machine-for-ruby-on-rails/)